# 2 DC motors & 1 servo for steering rc car

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

im working on an RC car project and im using 2 DC motors as a rear wheels ,one servo motor on front for steering with a nano arduino as a microcontroller, HC 06-slave bluetooth receiver, and L298N module for Fwd/Rev and PWM. for my transmitter im using nano arduino a joystick and HC-06 master.

i need my joystick Y axis to drive fwd/rev and X axis for steering. i manged to test the servo alone for X axis steering and it worked, also when tested the code for FWD/REV  on Y axis it worked.. however when i combine my code it doesn't work my servo starts shaking and my DC motors start responding to x and y!!

can someone help me pls.

here are the codes im using:

Master code (transmitter);

```
    //                == MASTER DEVICE - Joystick ==

    //int xAxis, yAxis;
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth 
    module
    }
    void loop() {
    xAxis = analogRead(A0); // Read Joysticks X-axis
    yAxis = analogRead(A1); // Read Joysticks Y-axis

    // Send the values via the serial port to the slave HC-05 Bluetooth 
    device
    Serial.write(xAxis/4); // Dividing by 4 for converting from 0 - 
    1023 to 0 - 256, (1 byte) range
    Serial.write(yAxis/4);
    delay(20);
    }
```

slave code (servo only);

```
    #include <Servo.h>
    Servo myServo;
    int yAxis;
    void setup() {
    myServo.attach(3);
    Serial.begin(9600); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth 
    module
    }
    void loop() {
    yAxis = 510 / 4;

      // Read the incoming data from the Joystick, or the master                 
      Bluetooth device
    if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from 
    the serial port
    yAxis = Serial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
      }
    delay(10);

    myServo.write(yAxis);
    delay(10);
    }
```

slave code for DC motors FWD/REV;

```
#include <Servo.h>
#define enA 9
#define in1 4
#define in2 5
#define enB 10
#define in3 6
#define in4 7
//int servoPin = 3;
int xAxis;
unsigned int  x = 0;
unsigned int  y = 0;
int motorSpeedA = 0;
int motorSpeedB = 0;
//Servo Servo1; 
void setup() {
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
//  Servo1.attach(servoPin);
}
void loop() {
  // Default value - no movement when the Joystick stays in the center
  x = 510 / 4;
  y = 510 / 4;
  // Read the incoming data from the Joystick, or the master Bluetooth device
  while (Serial.available() >= 2) {
    x = Serial.read();
//    delay(10);
//    y = Serial.read();
  }
  delay(10);
  // Convert back the 0 - 255 range to 0 - 1023, suitable for motor control code below
  xAxis = x*4;
//  yAxis = y*4;
  // Y-axis used for forward and backward control
  if (xAxis < 470) {
    // Set Motor A backward
    digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    // Set Motor B backward
    digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    // Convert the declining Y-axis readings for going backward from 470 to 0 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(xAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(xAxis, 470, 0, 0, 255);
  }
  else if (xAxis > 550) {
    // Set Motor A forward
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    // Set Motor B forward
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
    // Convert the increasing Y-axis readings for going forward from 550 to 1023 into 0 to 255 value for the PWM signal for increasing the motor speed
    motorSpeedA = map(xAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
    motorSpeedB = map(xAxis, 550, 1023, 0, 255);
  }
  // If joystick stays in middle the motors are not moving
  else {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }
    if (motorSpeedA < 70) {
    motorSpeedA = 0;
  }
  if (motorSpeedB < 70) {
    motorSpeedB = 0;
  }
  analogWrite(enA, motorSpeedA); // Send PWM signal to motor A
  analogWrite(enB, motorSpeedB); // Send PWM signal to motor B
}
```

i want to combine them so one of the axis is for DC motors FWD/REV and the other axis is for servo motor right/left.

Comment: Fix your code formatting. It's hard to read and as it is, it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You must be more explicit with the data you send.

Don't send x=20,y=30 as char[2]={20,30}.

A minimum would be char[4]={'x',20,'y',30}.

Then you will check that you receive complete datagram of 4 char, and then you can check that you don't confuse x with y.